# How to resolve pytz warning on Google App Engine cron dev server

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

On the crons page of my app engine dev server admin URL http://localhost:8000/cron

It's showing a warning about pytz for the cron entry which is set to timezone Europe/London:

```
pytz is required to calculate future run times for cron jobs with timezones.
```

I already have pytz, it's installed, I'm using it in the app and in crons, and it's fine on production servers.

How can I get rid of this warning? I've tried adding including it on my app.yaml libraries:

```
libraries:
- name: pytz
  version: latest
```

but no difference. Adding a 'libraries' section to cron.yaml causes an error. It doesn't affect anything really since crons don't run automatically in dev, but I want to avoid that warning.

My cron.yaml file is:

```
cron:
- description: timed cron job
  url: /tasks/monday-at-9
  schedule: every monday 09:00
  timezone: Europe/London
```

and the error/warning on the dev server is:

```
pytz is required to calculate future run times for cron jobs with timezones
```

even though I have pytz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ok now, a few weeks later. No red warning on my dev admin cron list page and it correctly tells me the times they would run in production, in the right time zones.

My cron.yaml file looks something like this:

```
cron:
    - description: My task
      url: /tasks/task-1
      schedule: every day 09:01
      timezone: Europe/London
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/release-notes

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the standard or flexible environment?

For the standard environment, the following isn't helpful:

```
libraries:
- name: pytz
  version: latest
```

because Google does not provide `pytz`.  Maybe it is even the cause of the problem...

I upload `pytz` with my app and make sure that is on the Python search path.  E.g., in the root directory of the project or in a folder that you've added with `vendor.add`.  I don't ever get the error you see.

I assume you are using one of the GAE specific versions of `pytz` (like this [one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gae-pytz/2016.3)) and not the general one because you can't use the general one.

Comment: Thanks. I'm in the standard environment and that libraries comment was just an attempt, since I need it for MySQL etc..  I'm using pytz.gae in my code and that works ok. It seems like this error is coming from my cron.yaml file & its parse from GAE, rather than the eventual task code in my app. It's only on the dev console that I see the warning, when using timezones in my cron entries in cron.yaml.

Comment: pytz is included with App Engine now ([see the list of libraries here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27)) but it doesn't work with dev_appserver as of this writing. :( There is an open ticket for [fixing the problem with dev_appserver](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35876507#comment31).